# send Request using Https with C++/MFC

Tags: visual-c++, https, mfc

my code:

```
CHttpFile* pFile = pHttpConnect->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, _T("/pass/serviceLoginAuth2"), NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE);  
pFile->SendRequest(NULL, 0, szRequest, _tcslen(szRequest)+1);
```

the code i create CHttpFile and send content.i use it to login website.the content of Request I capture :fiddler.network.https> Failed to secure existing connection for xxxxx.xx.com. 
the attribute of protocol still is HTTP,and did not send my post data.It seem like have exception when connect to sever.

Comment: How do you obtain `pHttpConnect`? You need to specify the port number of `INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT` (aka 443) at the time you create `CHttpConnection`: the default of `INTERNET_INVALID_PORT_NUMBER` won't cut it (it would result in the default HTTP port 80 being used).

Comment: INTERNET_PORT nPort = 80;  
  CHttpConnection* pHttpConnect = session.GetHttpConnection(_T("xxx.xxxx.com"), nPort); thank you

Comment: So, pass 443 there instead. That's the port HTTPS uses.

Comment: but i still fail to login,i have the same POST message just like th webbroser send,but they are different in (Tunnel to) action().i mean the content of (Tunnel to).

Comment: What is this "Tunnel to" of which you speak? I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe the client get key from server,i am not sure.i use fiddler to Capturing and always see this packet send before POST packet